# Lots of errors on apt-get update

Tags: apt

So I've only just installed ubuntu on my laptop, as I'd like to get more comfortable with it.
Doing apt-get update gives me a hell of a lot of 404 errors, followed by failed to fetch errors. 
I also can't seem to install chrome, as after downloading the executable it says it's missing a dependency (Which i tried to fix via google help, but none of the results fixed it as they did for others) 
I've read a few threads regarding similar things to what I'm experiencing but nothing seems to fix it.
Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's the version of Ubuntu you're using?

Comment: Uhh 12.10, It's an installation disc that I made quite a while ago that I decided to install

Comment: And now realising my old version I decided to run the software updater, to which I get an error saying failed to download repository information check your internet connection.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right, muru. My mistake, I think i'll have to create new installation media to update, the steps on that other question don't seem to work for my version, do you have any suggestions to add, possibly? (Thanks for the help!)

Comment: Which step are you having problems with? Editing the sources, `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: As it is a fresh install, it is far easier , faster, and more reliable to simply do a fresh install of a supported release.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 Version (Quantal Quetzal ) has limited update support till May 2014.

Therefor the repositories are not available for the requested update request.

Regarding Chrome, probably you are trying to run newer version of Chrome which needs newer versions of lib files that cannot be found in 12.10 version.

I recommend to download Long Term Support version if you are looking for stability, which in this case can be 14.04 version as it has support till April 2019 which is another 5 years of support.